# How to fix Next 13's Hydration error - "There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary ..."

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am facing the following issue while using Next.js 13 -

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <html>.
```

When I try to render the PostBox component on the screen, there is always a hydration error. I do not understand what about my code is causing the error.

I tried all the fixes available on the internet and I'm still stuck on the same issue.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Below is my code -

layout.tsx

```js
import './globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import Provider from '@/components/provider'; // next auth session provider
import {ApolloWrapper} from '../apollo-client'; // Apollo client provider
import Header from '@/components/Header';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <ApolloWrapper>
        <Provider>
            <Header />
            <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </Provider>
      </ApolloWrapper>
    </html>
  );
}
```

page.tsx

```js
"use client"

import PostBox from "@/components/PostBox";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, [])

  return (
    mounted && (
        <PostBox /> {/* the component that is causing the issue */}
    )
  );
}
```

PostBox.tsx

```js
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "./Avatar";

function PostBox() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  return (
    <form>
      <label className="flex items-center space-x-3">
        <Avatar />
        <input
          disabled={!session}
          className="flex-1 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-2 pl-5 outline-none"
          type="text"
          placeholder={session ? "Create a post" : "Sign in to post"}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}

export default PostBox;
```

Comment: What's the `useEffect` used for when rendering the `PostBox` component?

Comment: Code that is only supposed to run in the browser should be executed inside useEffect. That's required because the first render should match the initial render of the server. If you manipulate that result it creates a mismatch and React won't be able to hydrate the page successfully.

Find out more here - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My case

I had the same error and was difficult found the solution:

I used "use client" in components but the message of "Hydration" never showed, when I used "redux provider" in app/layout worked fine but the problem came when I used useSelector and use dispatch inside of **client components** the error "Hydration" came .

### Solution

I found the solution with lucky XD, you have that use one variable of state and check on charge with that before use your client tool and show when this checker(`mounted`) is ready.

page.tsx

```js
"use client"

import PostBox from "@/components/PostBox";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, [])

  return (
        <PostBox /> 
  );
}
```

ButtonSession.tsx

```js
"use client";
export default function ButtonSession() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
   return <input
    disabled={!session}
    className="flex-1 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-2 pl-5 outline-none"
    type="text"
    placeholder={session ? "Create a post" : "Sign in to post"}
  />
}
```

PostBox.tsx

```js
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "./Avatar";
import ButtonSession from "./ButtonSession"

function PostBox() {
  
  
 useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) {
    return null;
  }
  

  return (
    <form>
      <label className="flex items-center space-x-3">
        <Avatar />
        { mounted ? <ButtonSession/> : <></>}
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}

export default PostBox;
```